# Collect the Dropdown List from Link using Request

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, request

I have a link as below:

url = "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY&date=9JAN2020"

I want to collect all the **Expiry Date** available as per the image below:

[image: CollectDatefrom Image]

```
My Code:
########################
import pandas as pd
from requests import Session
import os, time, sys
from datetime import datetime

s = Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
                         'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
                         'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}
# Add headers
s.headers.update(headers)

URL = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp'
params = {'symbolCode':9999,'symbol':'BANKNIFTY','instrument': '-','date': '9JAN2020','segmentLink': 17}
res = s.get(URL, params=params)

df1 = pd.read_html(res.content)[0]
df2 = pd.read_html(res.content)[1]
```

Not able to get the values in df1 nor df2

Comment: show your code and full error message. What did you try?

Comment: Can you post what you tried

Comment: did you try to use `requests` + `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml` ?

Comment: Sir, I have added my code for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs minimal knowlege of `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`

```
import requests
import lxml.html

url = 'https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY&date=9JAN2020'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)

items = soup.xpath('//form[@id="ocForm"]//option/text()')
print(items)
```

Result

```
[' Select ', '9JAN2020', '16JAN2020', '23JAN2020', '30JAN2020', '6FEB2020', '13FEB2020', '20FEB2020', '27FEB2020', '5MAR2020', '26MAR2020']
```

Comment: Sir, is there any other way of getting those values. I mean without using lxml.html

Comment: you can use `BeautifulSoup` instead of `lxml`. But if you want you can even use regex or normal string functions but it can be much complex.

Comment: Yea. Got it. Many Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import Session
import lxml.html


s = Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
            'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
            'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}
# Add headers
s.headers.update(headers)

URL = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp'
params = {'symbolCode':9999,'symbol':'BANKNIFTY','instrument': 'OPTIDX','date': '-','segmentLink': 17}
res = s.get(URL, params=params)
soup = lxml.html.fromstring(res.text)
items = soup.xpath('//form[@id="ocForm"]//option/text()')
print(items)

text = pd.read_html(res.content)[0].loc[0, 1]
print(text)
```